# Count rows which do not contain some string-Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to count the rows where the dataframe do not contain some string. Eg:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1.1, 1.1, 1.1, 2.6, 2.5, 3.4,2.6,2.6,3.4,3.4,2.6,1.1,1.1,3.3], list('AAABBBBABCBDDD'), ['x/y/z','x/y','x/y/z/n','x/u','x','x/u/v','x/y/z','x','x/u/v/b','-','x/y','x/y/z','x','x/u/v/w']]).T
df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3']

   col1 col2     col3
0   1.1    A    x/y/z
1   1.1    A      x/y
2   1.1    A  x/y/z/n
3   2.6    B      x/u
4   2.5    B        x
5   3.4    B    x/u/v
6   2.6    B    x/y/z
7   2.6    A        x
8   3.4    B  x/u/v/b
9   3.4    C        -
10  2.6    B      x/y
11  1.1    D    x/y/z
12  1.1    D        x
13  3.3    D  x/u/v/w
```

In the above dataframe I want to count the rows which do not contain 'u' or 'z'. I know how to use str.contains to get the rows with specific strings.

```
df.col3.str.contains('u|z')
```

How to get the count of "not" part?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try:

```
~df.col3.str.contains('u|z')
```

### Update

To Count, use

```
(~df.col3.str.contains('u|z')).sum()
```

Comment: Is this fine to get the count of rows? ~df.col3.str.contains('u|z').value_counts()

Comment: waitingkuo: Ok Thanks got what I wanted..:)

Comment: @waitingkuo I think you want ``sum()``, not ``count()``. Counting includes both ``True`` and ``False`` and gives 14, not 6.

Comment: Thank you Dan, sorry for the misleading, have updated the answer

Answer (score -1):

I might be misunderstanding but isn't this possible?

`if not df.col3.str.contains('u|z'):`

or

```
if df.col3.str.contains('u|z'):
    #do something
else: # will not contain a u or a z        
    #do something
```

Comment: ``df.col3.str.contains('u|z')`` returns a boolean array, so can't use pythonic ``and,or,not`` only the bitwise ``&,|,~``